# spring-boot saml: configure service provider entityId

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, saml, saml-2.0

Is there a way to configure the entityID of the service provider in the following configuration:

```
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          myapp:
            signing:
              credentials:
                - private-key-location: "classpath:private.pem"
                  certificate-location: "classpath:public.pem"
            identityprovider:
              entity-id: idp
              singlesignon:
                sign-request: false
                url: https://.../auth/realms/saml-demo/protocol/saml
```

Currently the identity provider is always receiving the following format:

```
{baseUrl}/saml2/service-provider-metadata/{registrationId}
```

For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/saml2/service-provider-metadata/myapp
```

Can this format be customized when using the yaml config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello this is how it works.

```
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          myapp:
            signing:
              credentials:
                - private-key-location: "classpath:private.pem"
                  certificate-location: "classpath:public.pem"
            entity-id: "http://localhost:8080/saml2/service-provider-metadata/myapp"
```

Don't use the  identityprovide. Just add the entity-id and it just works. The official documentation is wrong. From what I see.